# what is the best practise to merge seperate post collections data together?

Tags: mongodb

suppose i have 2 different `post` type, eg.  `HouseMarketPost` and `JobMarketPost`

they contain some same fields like `title`, `content`,`createdAt`, but most fields are  different, so i trade them as 2 seperate collections.

then i have a homepage need to show a merged post data from these 2 collections based on `createdAt`. also need to support pagination.

my solution so far is query the data seperately, for example, if the pagesize is 10, then i query 5 datas from `HouseMarketPost` and 5 from `JobMarketPost`, then cocact these data together. however as they are seperate query, the createdAt would be mix up.

`2 collections` is just for a example, in fact, i may have multiple post collections that far beyond 2.

so,what is the best practise to achvive this goal?

BTY, i can't use `unionWith`, cause the version of my mongodb is 4.0

Comment: Have you checked out [$unionWith](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/)?

Comment: i can't use unionWith, cause the version of my mongodb is 4.0. :(

Comment: There is a lot of ambiguity in between. What if you are selecting from 15 collections while having a page size of 10? Which results should be selected? Anyway, after imposing the db version constraint, your best bet might be either refactoring your schema or creating another centralized collection that stores a copy of the posts. Both of them are aiming to provide a single collection for you to query from.

Comment: that make sense, thanks for your advise, i will think about upgrading db version or adding an extra collection